# mapping xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

I can figure this without literally going to memory overflow (at least with altova mapforce) and hopefully will help others.

I have 2 xml files:

1st:

```
<item>
  <id>100</id>
  <title>some title</title>
  <subtitle>some subtitle</subtitle>
</item>
...
```

2nd:

```
<item>
  <id>100</id>
<item>
...
```

and I want to match (output XML) every item that matches 2nd XML `<id>` with 1st XML `<id>`, by using XSLT. I want to get all elements from matching 1st XML file. I expect this to be easy for those who know XSL or I expect my approach to be wrong

I guess second XML file will be referenced as XSL parameter, but I don't know how to reference it elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="first" select="document('first.xml')/root" />
. . .
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
  <span>title of item <xsl:value-of select="$id" /> is <xsl:value-of select="$first/item[id=$id]/title" /></span>
</xsl:template>
```